# Gifshot GIF chrashes on download

Tags: gif, animated-gif, animated

Using Gifshot i generate a link like this:

```
<a href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODl...hyADIAAAAACH/C05FVFNDQV" type="button" id="save-gif" class="btn btn-large btn-default" role="button" download="test.gif">Save</a>
```

When i try to download it my browser chrashes. I have tryed with different browsers and the same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

Believe I have just worked through the same problem - the issue isn't with Gifshot itself but with the amount of base64 data you can put in a download link (not sure if this is specific to GIFs or affects no-animated image types as well).

The solution I found was the reduce the dimensions and number of frames in my generated GIF to produce a smaller filesize. It was a bit of trial and error, but it looked to be once the filesize dropped below about 1MB that the download link started working.